# Triggering DOM element method on parent directive in Angular / Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, aframe

I'm currently experimenting with aframe.io and using the VR cursor to click a button and exit the VR experience.

What I want to happen is when the cursor-click event is triggered on the box and on the cardboard cursor click directive - that to then go to the vr-video-control directive so it can perform the exitVR() method on the scene. I know from looking around direct DOM manipulation should be done in 'link' but publicly available methods should be declared in 'controller' - so how do you access the $element attribute of 'link' in a method of 'controller'? Or is there a better approach than this?

Right now I can't access the scene element linked to the vr-video-control directive to trigger any methods.

My HTML looks like:

```html
<a-scene vr-video-control>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="video" src="video/video4.mp4" autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
      </a-assets>

      <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 180 0">
           
        <a-box id="videoLeftButton" cardboard-cursor-click cardboard-cursor-action="back" color="white" height="2" width="5" position="-7 0 10" rotation="0 -225 0"></a-box>
        <a-box id="videoRightButton" cardboard-cursor-click cardboard-cursor-action="forward" color="white" height="2" width="5" position="7 0 10" rotation="0 -135 0"></a-box>

      </a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
```

Where cardboard-cursor-click is one directive which looks like this

```js
 function CardboardCursorClick() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^^vrVideoControl',
    scope: { 
      cardboardCursorAction: '@'
    },
    link: (scope, element, attrs, videoControl) => {
      element.on('cursor-click', () => {
        console.log("Cursor click " + scope.cardboardCursorAction);
        videoControl.exitVR();
      });
    }
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'cardboardCursorClick',
  fn: CardboardCursorClick
};
```

and that relies on the parent directive vr-video-control:

```js
function VRVideoControl() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { item: '&' },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      this.exitVR = function(cursorAction) {
        //Trigger exitVR() on <a-scene>
      }
    }]
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'vrVideoControl',
  fn: VRVideoControl
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the scope in the directive I've realised I can publicly expose methods to other controllers while keeping DOM manipulation within the link method. I'm still new to Angular though so not certain this is the best approach?

```js
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      this.exitVR = function(cursorAction) {
        $scope.exitVR(cursorAction);
      };
    }],
    link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
      scope.exitVR = function(cursorAction) {
        var rawElement = angular.element(element)[0]
        rawElement.exitVR();
      };
    }
  };
```